# Get phone number of the device on it's range?

Tags: android

Is it possible to get the phone number of nearest phone or get certain information of the cellphone within it's range or nearest field?

Answer (score 2):

Tim has the right way to obtain the user's phone number. But from your question I understand you want to obtain phone numbers of adjacent devices.

You cannot retrieve phone numbers of adjacent phones in your area, that is unless your application is running on both of them and you're using GPS to track proximity. Then you'll be able to "Get phone numbers of adjacent devices".

As far as phone informations, your application also has to run on both adjacent phones in order to exchange them. They can be found in the [Build class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html).

Don't forget you'll have to add specific permissions in the manifest in order to accomplish what you're trying to do :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: This app http://code.google.com/p/moonblink/wiki/Tricorder could be able to get device signals..Maybe there's a way we could get and scan the phone number of a nearest device.

Comment: Perhaps, I'm not aware of what this application does. But I'm almost certain that there are no legitimate ways of accomplishing what you're trying to be without the consent of both users/phones.

Answer (score -2):

Your question is unclear, you will have better luck if you elaborate some more.

You can use this to retrieve the phone number of the device you are running on:

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Comment: not the phone that I am running but the phone within it's range.Like a radar.